# Moment of Inertia Problem

Tags: structural-engineering, statics

Im currently studying for the FE exam and I came across a problem from a FE practice test that I'm confused on. The specific question is on the parallel axis theorem of a trapezoid and the D value that im supposed use. In the solution, the D value is the (entire height - the y distance to the requested axis). However, I was under the impression that D was the distance from the centroid of the object to the desired axis. I calculated yc of the trapezoid and subtracted the desired axis length from that. Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are correct. The distance from the base to the centroid is h(2a+b)/3(a+b) = 2.67, and y' = 4.5-2.67 = 1.83, so Ix' is greater than the solution given. But, unfortunately, "D" is still the best answer :)